# How do i Re-run pipeline with only failed activities/Dataset in Azure Data Factory V2?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am running a pipeline where i am looping through all the tables in INFORMATION.SCHEMA.TABLES and copying it onto Azure Data lake store.My question is how do i run this pipeline for the failed tables only if any of the table fails to copy?

[image]

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, but you have to provide more information about your case.

Comment: Hi Martin,Added an image for reference. Is there any way to run only the failed activity? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes there is a way, but in my opinion its not a good practice. Why is it failing? Maybe we can do something so it doesnt run for 10 mins and then fails.

Comment: This is a legitimate question and has all the details needed.  The question isn’t about “why” the job is failing, it is about “how” to recover on errors.  ADFv1 and ADFv2 differ: please add the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach I’ve found is to code your process to:

```
0. Yes, root cause the failure and identify if it is something wrong with the pipeline or if it is a “feature” of your dependency you have to code around.

1. Be idempotent.  If your process ensures a clean state as the very first step, similar to Command Design pattern’s undo (but more naive), then your process can re-execute. 

    * with #1, you can safely use “retry” in your pipeline activities, along with sufficient time between retries.
    * this is an ADFv1 or v2 compatible approach

2. If ADFv2, then you have more options and can have more complex logic to handle errors:

    * for the activity that is failing, wrap this in an until-success loop, and be sure to include a bound on execution.  
    * you can add more activities in the loop to handle failure and log, notify, or resolve known failure conditions due to externalities out of your control.

3. You can also use asynchronous communication to future process executions that save success to a central store.  Then later executions “if” I already was successful then stop processing before the activity.  

    * this is powerful for more generalized pipelines, since you can choose where to begin

4. Last resort I know (and I would love to learn new ways to handle) is manual re-execution of failed activities.
```

Hope this helps,
J

Comment: 2nd Option, Wrapping it into Unit-Success loop worked for me.Regarding your 4th point, I dont see any option to run the failed activityManually. PIpeline Re-run option is there but not for the failed activity. Would be much appreciated if you can put some light on that as well.Thanks.